# Select multiple items from a listbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select multiple values from a ListBox.
I enabled the `SelectionMode` as `multiple`. I am able to select multiple values, but only one value is going to the database. I used `Listbox.SelectedValue.ToString()`.

Please help me out how to get that multiple values into the database?

Comment: How do you plan to send the multiple values to database?

Comment: if i am choosing A,B,C then these 3 values should go to a single row in the database.

Answer (score 2):

[ListBox.SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return only one value. You need to use [ListBox.SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and then adjust your code accordingly to insert multiple values into the database.

Comment: should it b entered it into an array or something? i am getting error when i put selecteditems.

Answer (score 0):

Using **foreach** loop we can get multiple selected values in ListBox

```
    foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (li.Selected)
        {
            lblValues.Text += li.Text+"<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Check this link for more in details: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-get-multiple-selected-value-in-listbox-control-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1047.aspx